# (Interaction Studio) What could be the reason why an anonimous user - even after logging in - is not merged into the existing user?

Tags: identity, cookies, userrecordaccess, interaction-studio, personalization

I am facing an issue with **Personalization** (former Interaction Studio): my website has a public area and a private one, that users can access after login; in both these 2 pages we have Personalization installed.

The issue is that when a user **logs out** from the private area, it becomes an unknown user in Personalization, even though the browser, device and cookies are fro the same session.
Moreover, when the user log back in, all the info from the "unknown session" **is not merged into the already existing profile**.

I have been thinking this could be related to the settings, because we have been using an encrypted contact key as the **Identity attribute** to use as the WebSDK Identity; the **Web SDK Cookie Secure Attribute** has not been flagged.

So we tried to change the identifier to "Profile ID", and we toggled the WEB SDK Cookie feature, but with no change in the results.

What do you think could be the root of this issue? Why the cookie is not working? Is another Unique ID more useful to adopt?

Thank you in advance for any help!